# regex inside or condition inside group value?

Tags: regex

```
 regex = /(utest|ctftest)>(\w+) {('xmlfile':'(\w+).xml.*|.*)}/g;
  match = regex.exec(data);
```

In this regex inside `{('xmlfile':'(\w+).xml.*|.*)`} how to get the inside `(\w+)` group value. 
Please help me.

Comment: This isn't a valid regex.

Comment: What exactly are you trying to do ?

Comment: show the input string (`data`)

Comment: input string is 1.  utest>PreCommitSWATTest {'PLIMode' : 'None'} 2.utest>SWATTest {'xmlfile':'PLI_4KB_aligned.xml', 'GiveUpTime':'30'}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The inside `(\w+)` match is stored as fourth match group of your `match` variable. So you can get it by using

```
console.log(match[4]);
```

As you can also see on regex101: https://regex101.com/r/aD3zI8/2

Answer (score 0):

I have tested:

- your example input `some times utest>SWATTest {'xmlfile':'PLI_4KB_aligned.xml', 'GiveUpTime':'30'}`
- with notepad++ 6.8.6 (which has PCRE support)

Some remarks (as have been pointed out in the comments above):

- the re is not valid: use `\{` and `\}` to match a literal parenthesis
- the backreferences are counted by the openning `(`, you want something that starts at the fourth `(`, use `\4` or `$4`